# Placing page numbers with Fancyhdr

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I have looked through many of the posts on this website, but I am still having trouble placing my page numbers in latex the way I want it.

Essentially, I want to mimic the way MS Word formats page numbers when placed in the top right hand corner.  The code I am using places the page number at roughly the same level as my section heading.  By the looks of it, if I could just move the page# up a few points, but have the section title stay where it is, everything would look okay.  Any help would be appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{dcolumn, pstricks, multirow}
\usepackage{epsfig, subfigure, subfloat, graphicx, float}
\usepackage{anysize, setspace}
\usepackage{verbatim, rotating}
\usepackage{epsfig,graphicx}
\usepackage[abbr]{harvard}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1.5in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[block] 
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\filcenter}{\fbox{\itshape\thesection}}{1em}{}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand*{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[RO,RE]{\thepage} %RO=right odd, RE=right even 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}

 \setcounter{page}{34} 
\section*{Appendix A: Methodology} 

stuff here

\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't load both `fullpage` and `geometry`: they fight each other.

Comment: Please always remove all irrelevant packages before posting a question here! See [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) (irrelevant = problem shows up without the package)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you process your document, you get three warnings; two of them directly concern your problem:

> Package Fancyhdr Warning: \fancyhead's `E' option without twoside
>   option is useless on input line 27.
>
> Package Fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (0.0pt): Make it at
>   least 14.49998pt.

The first one, tells you that, unless you activate the `twoside` class option, `E` (for Even) won't have any effect (similar remark applies to `O`). I added the option in my example code below (if you don't want that option, delete it and remove `E` and `O` from your `fancyhdr` definitions). Also, there's no need to use `[RE,RO]`, since this is equivalent to just `[R]`.

The second one, tells you that the default reserves spacing for your header is too small and that you need to increase it using

```
\setlength\headheight{14.5pt}
```

Your code, after incorporating the changes:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{dcolumn, pstricks, multirow}
\usepackage{epsfig, subfigure, subfloat, graphicx, float}
\usepackage{anysize, setspace}
\usepackage{verbatim, rotating}
\usepackage{epsfig,graphicx}
\usepackage[abbr]{harvard}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1.5in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[block] 
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries\filcenter}{\fbox{\itshape\thesection}}{1em}{}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand*{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage} %R right on all pages 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\setlength\headheight{14.5pt}
\begin{document}

 \setcounter{page}{34} 
\section*{Appendix A: Methodology} 

stuff here

\end{document}
```

I added the `showframe` option to `geometry` to have some frames as visual guides:

[image]

By the way, do you really need all those packages in your preamble? Notice also that you are loading the same package more than once (avoid this). Also, you load `graphics` and `graphicx`, it's enough to load the latter.

If you want to move the header further up, you can increase the `headsep` length; since you are already loading `geometry`, you can use its `headsep` key:

```
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1.5in, left=1in, right=1in,headsep=1cm]{geometry}
```

To move the page number to the right, you can use `\fancyheadoffset`, as in

```
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\setlength\headheight{14.5pt}
\fancyheadoffset[R]{1cm}
```

Of course, instead of `1cm`, use the lengths that best suit your needs.

Comment: That is odd.  My processor does not return those errors.  I am using Miktex.  Is there a way to add space between the section header and page number?  Setting the \headheight to at least 15 only affects the header size whereas I want to move only the page number up and to the right without moving the section heading.

Comment: @MarcinWiezel The messages are not *errors*, they are *warnings* (different things; you can see them in the output console and perhaps your editor also has a mechanism for displaying them). The section title doesn't move with the modification of `\headheight`; this reserves space for the header. Do you want to move the page number still further up? I wouldn't suggest you moving it to the right (it will fall outside the margins), but if you want to, I'll tell you how tou can achieve it.

Comment: @MarcinWiezel please see my updated answer; I incorporated suggestions to move the number up and to the right.

Comment: that did the trick.